# How to Save a Material as an Image

Tags: texturing, materials, baking

I am making some photo-realistic rocks in Cycles, and I made a material using nodes, and combined two images using a bunch of modifiers and then connected them to the rocks material node. How can I take the rocks material and save it as an image? I've tried to bake it, but I can never find where the baked image is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the UV/Image Editor?

Comment: Yes, i saw the images that i have imported to blender but not the Baked image.

Comment: Baking writes the baked image to the image used by active image node of the material. This may be an existing image if you haven't setup one for baking. Read the [third paragraph](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/baking.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Render output panel is in: Properties Panel->Render->Output

-

https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html#output-panel

Comment: This is the output folder for rendered images. Im looking for where baked images are saved.

Comment: pretty sure thats the same thing

Comment: Edit: Deleted my last comment for some reason i can only select images that are being put into the node pipeline, not the end result. Any answers there?

Comment: User Preferences->Render Layers-> passes is where you choose what gets baked.

Comment: thank you, thats what i needed now i can use the baked images

Answer (score 1):

One way to.save the material as an image is to create a plane object of an appropriate size and apply the material to the plane. Then create a lighting and camera set up you find satisfactory, render the image of the plane, and save the rendered image.